# How to get ssl/tls certificate from https response in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, npm, https, handshake

I'm implementing a certificate automation service, and I want to verify the certificate is deployed correctly by making a https request after deployment, the https response should bring me the new deployed certificate's info, such as issue date and expires date.

I know this is something part of the socket programming, so I wondered if anyone knows there are some existing packages that I can use.

If there is no such packages, I may go deeper to learn some handshake flows and do it with Socket directly.

---

Ps: The most closest things I know is when implementing a custom x509 trust manager in JAVA, it do support verifying the certificate from the client side.

Comment: I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge and https://www.npmjs.com/package/certnames, I think I'm almost there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The https://www.npmjs.com/package/certnames package inspires me, then I found I can do it with bundled `tls` module directly, as the certificate is transfered through tls layer, so we don't need to make a http request to get it.

```
import * as tls from 'tls';

test('test', function (done) {
  let host = 'httpbin.org';
  let socket = tls.connect({
    port:443, 
    host,
    servername: host, // this is required in case the server enabled SNI
  }, () => {
    let x509Certificate = socket.getPeerX509Certificate();

    expect(x509Certificate.subject).toBe('CN=httpbin.org');

    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant solution, thank you for this! Also to comply with site rules, I have to add something useful to this comment, so here it is: `https.requests` callback's `connection` property is deprecated and getPeerCertificate does not exists in `socket`, at least in TypeScript definition. Actually it just stuck and does not do anything, so this is the only working low-level solution for node without any additional dependencies.

Comment: @VityaSchel `getPeerCertificate`/`getPeerX509Certificate` belongs to `TLSSocket`. You could find more documents here: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/tls.html